# new array values on each submit php

Tags: php, file-handling

Dont know much PHP and wonder how I can get the new values from an array each time I submit, I have a form with 5 fields, the form sends the information to a txt-file then I want to take only the two first items each time the form submits and display it in a list item, but cant seem to figure out how the loop should work? any tips please?

For now I have this and it successfully prints out the fist textblock in the txt-file, but when I submit the form again nothing happens, what is wrong?

```
$myFile = 'demo.txt';
$content = file_get_contents('demo.txt');
$content_array = explode(";", $content);

<div id="info_php">
       <ul id="list_php">
            <?php for($i=count($content_array); $i < 1; $i--);
             echo '<li>'; echo $content_array[0]; echo'</li>';?>
        </ul>       
</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't be bothered to use capital letters? Then I cannot be bothered to help you for free.

Comment: ok, what information? I have just started learning PHP so dont really know what you mean...?

Comment: You don't have any form fields in that html.... no `<input>` or `<textarea>` (or `<form>` for that matter), no data to submit.

Comment: the form is in the same page, do you want to se the form aswell? because the form works and sends all of the information to the txt-file like: field1;field2;field3;field4;field5 then a new row and the same thing again... what i wanted with the loop was to get only field1 and field2 and display in a list-element at the same page beside the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is it!

```
<?php
    $myFile = 'demo.txt';
    $content = file_get_contents($myFile);
    $content_array2 = explode("\n", $content);      
?>


<?php for($i = 0; $i < count($content_array2); $i++):
       $values = explode(';', $content_array2[$i]);?>
       <li><?php echo $values[0].$values[1]; ?></li>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in syntax, the for loop is terminated by semicolon, and you are printing only the first element as `$content_array[0]`, instead of using the loop variable. Try this:

```
 <?php 
 for($i=count($content_array); $i < 1; $i--) {
     echo '<li>'; echo $content_array[$i]; echo'</li>'; 
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: now it just prints a small circle? no information, as I said I have little knowledge of PHP so maybe there is something wrong with the loop?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is change your loop like this:

```
<?php
    $count = count($content_array); // total rows
    $limit = $count > 2 ? $count - 2 : 0; // at most we want two rows
    for ($i = $count; $i > limit; $i--) {
        echo '<li>' . $content_array[$i - 1] . '</li>';
    }
?>
```

This will get the last two rows of the txt file

Comment: the last two rows of the txt file? maybe you missunderstood, its hard to explain but lets say i have submited the form three times then the txt file looks like this: field1;field2;field3;field4;field5 /n field1;field2;field3;field4;field5 /n field1;field2;field3;field4;field5 /n this should generate three list-elements that only displays field1 an field2 on each list-element or maybe i missunderstood you...

Comment: with the code you posted it says undefined offset: 1 at the line with the echo?

Comment: Oh sorry about that! I forgot the [$i - 1]. I've updated that line

Comment: ok, sorry but now it just prints out everything in the txt-file in one list-element?

Comment: and it prints the semicolons to, wich should be gone with the explode?

Comment: have been struggeling with this for days and its strange that it should be so hard to create elements with info from an array, dont know much javascript either but its much simpler in js..

Comment: Yeah that's bizarre. The explode(';', $content) should get rid of the semi colons.  The only way it wouldn't is if there is some type of encoding.  Can you view the source of the page? Does it show semicolons or some strange character like &#59;